# Serialização e Deserialização JSON em aplicação desktop

Tags: c#, json, serialização

> {"result":[[{"CodigoReduzido":"019076-3","Estoque":200,"Preco":900.77,"PrecoST":225.19,"Descricao":"
>   PLACA DE VIDEO ASUS AMD RADEON R5 230 1GB DDR3 64BITS R5230-SL-1GD3-L
>   *IMP","Grupo":"PLACA DE VIDEO","Marca":"ASUS","Origem":6,"NCM":"8473.30.43","EAN":"0000000000000","PesoBruto":0,"Largura":0,"Altura":0,"Profundidade":0,"Garantia":"12
>   Meses","AliqIPI":0,"AliqICMS":12,"Unidade":"PC","MultiploVenda":1,"Link":"https://www2.meusite.com.br/localnew/_img/fotos_produtos/019076-3.jpg","PartNumber":"R5230-SL-1GD3-L"}]]}

Estou Enviando o Código que estou desenvolvendo..

```
    private void ButtonConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileContents;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        string html = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = fileContents;
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Result paging = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Result>(fileContents);
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + paging.Descricao;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {

            //richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + paging.results[i].id + " ";
            //richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + paging.results[i].buyer.id + " ";
            //richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + paging.results[i].buyer.first_name + " ";



        }

    }
    public class Result
    {
        public string CodigoReduzido { get; set; }
        public int Estoque { get; set; }
        public double Preco { get; set; }
        public double PrecoST { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Grupo { get; set; }
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        public int Origem { get; set; }
        public string NCM { get; set; }
        public string EAN { get; set; }
        public double PesoBruto { get; set; }
        public int Largura { get; set; }
        public int Altura { get; set; }
        public int Profundidade { get; set; }
        public string Garantia { get; set; }
        public int AliqIPI { get; set; }
        public int AliqICMS { get; set; }
        public string Unidade { get; set; }
        public int MultiploVenda { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    }
```

**Utilizando json2csharp
generate c# classes from json**

```
    public class RootObject
    {
         public List<List<>> result { get; set; }
    }
```

Mais eu não consegui utilizar dessa maneira..
Agora creio que consegui explicar melhor

Agradeco a ajuda dos amigos...

Comment: Clique em [edit] e ponha seu código de deserialização aí. Creio que está funcionando, o problema é que você tem que acessar estes valores como uma array dentro de outra para pegar os valores, apenas isso.

Comment: _Utilizando o próprio Visual Studio ele me mostrou que teria que usar para acessar as array da seguinte maneira paging[0].[0]  Creio que meu problema esta na parte das classes da estrutura JSON....  como fazer.._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido Problema de Duas Maneiras

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<List<Result>> result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string CodigoReduzido { get; set; }
        public int Estoque { get; set; }
        public double Preco { get; set; }
        public double PrecoST { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Grupo { get; set; }
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        public int Origem { get; set; }
        public string NCM { get; set; }
        public string EAN { get; set; }
        public double PesoBruto { get; set; }
        public int Largura { get; set; }
        public int Altura { get; set; }
        public int Profundidade { get; set; }
        public string Garantia { get; set; }
        public int AliqIPI { get; set; }
        public int AliqICMS { get; set; }
        public string Unidade { get; set; }
        public int MultiploVenda { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**Resolvido o problema da Seguinte Maneira Utilizando JSON.NET**

```
    private void Json2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileContents;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
            string html = String.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            richTextBox1.Text = fileContents;

            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(fileContents));
            RootObject rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(fileContents);
            textBox2.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
               for (int j = 0; j < rootobject.result[i].Count() ; j++)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + rootobject.result[i][j].CodigoReduzido + "   ";
                    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "  " + rootobject.result[i][j].Descricao + "\r\n";
                    */* aqui voce coloca o restante dos seus campos */*
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox3.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

**Solução usando Modo Nativo JavaScriptSerializer**

```
    private void ButtonConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileContents;
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
            string html = String.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            richTextBox1.Text = fileContents;
            JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            RootObject rootobject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(fileContents);
            textBox2.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < rootobject.result[i].Count() ; j++)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + rootobject.result[i][j].CodigoReduzido + "   ";
                    */* aqui voce coloca o restante dos seus campos */*
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Nativamente, você pode utilizar a classe `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

Serializa o objeto `obj`.

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(objStr);
```

Faz o papel contrário, desserializando a string `objStr` para o tipo `T`.

Comment: Obrigo pela ajuda até o momento..   fiz ja uma parte, mais ainda não consigo desvendar esse maledito rsrsr

Comment: _Resolvi das duas maneiras, nativamente e JSON NET, Obrigado pela ajuda !!!_

Answer (score 1):

O pacote JSON.NET faz a serialização de um objeto pra você:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Assim:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(produto);
```

E desserializando:

```
var produto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Produto>(jsonString);
```

A documentação completa [está aqui](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda...   estou tentando utilizar a forma nativa..  primeiro..  mais  a briga continua... obrigado

Comment: _Resolvi das duas maneiras, nativamente e JSON NET, Obrigado pela ajuda !!!_