# Como acessar propriedade de objeto Json?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Estou recebendo via Ajax um objeto Json, e gostaria de transformá-lo em um objeto C# e acessar suas propriedades.
Como posso fazer isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acabei invertendo o nome das variáveis (`objeto`, `itens`), a primeira são os itens, e a segunda os objetos em si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda do [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32757/serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-deserializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-json-em-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-desktop) postado pelo Marciano.Andrade no comentário da minha pergunta, cheguei a solução.

 
A questão é que estou recebendo uma lista de objetos, então bastava criar um array de tais objetos.

Tudo se resolveu com a seguinte linha:

```
Aluno[] aluno = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Aluno[]>(models);
```